# Dynamically reading attributes from lists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Right now I've got a ul list which contains a number of radio button options and a separate table. When a user clicks an option from the ul list, it adds a row to the table containing the 'category' and 'select' li attributes (but hard-coded) and a textarea for the user to write notes. I'm new to jQuery so right now everything is hard-coded which is obviously not ideal.

Here's an example of the code I have right now. First the basic list users select options from:

```
<ul class="current_medication">
      <li class="category" title="Chronic Pain Referral">Chronic Pain Referral
        <ul>
        <li class="select" title="Chronic referral"><input type="radio" class="addRow1" id="radio1" name="modalities" value="1">
           <label for="radio1">Chronic referral</label></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Then the jQuery code which adds a table row when users click on the radio option:

```
$('.addRow1').click(function() {
$('.mainTable > tbody:last').one().append('<tr style="text-align:center"><td>Chronic Pain Referral</td><td>Chronic referral</td><td><textarea name="notes"></textarea></td></tr>');
});
```

As you can see it's hard-coded, so another option on the  list will have the class 'addRow2' and there will be a jQuery function for that too similar to addRow1 with the info between the td tags changed.

What I would like is to be able to automate this by somehow reading the title attributes for the category and select 'li's so I can just have one addRow function for them all. I assume the answer lies somewhere with .attr() but I'm not sure how to get it to read from the radio button that was clicked and then get the relevant info from that preceding 'li's closest to the radio button containing the title attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code in the click binding to:

```
$('.mainTable > tbody:last').one().append(
    '<tr style="text-align:center"><td>' 
  + $(this).closest("li.category").attr("title")
  + '</td><td>'
  + $(this).closest("li.select").attr("title")
  + '</td><td><textarea name="notes"></textarea></td></tr>');
});
```

(if I did understand your question right).

But note it does not escape HTML, for example if your category `<li>` is:

```
<li class="category" title="Chronic Pain &lt;b&gt;Referral">
```

(it would display Chronic Pain **Referral**).

So I would rather do:

```
$('.addRow1').click(function() {
 var tr = $(
    '<tr style="text-align:center"><td class="cat"></td>' 
  + '<td class="sel"></td>'
  + '<td><textarea name="notes"></textarea></td></tr>');
 $('.mainTable > tbody:last').one().append(tr);
 tr.find(".cat").text($(this).closest("li.category").attr("title"));
 tr.find(".sel").text($(this).closest("li.select").attr("title"));
});
```

Comment: Should say it almost works, there is a problem with the second code section. It will overwrite all existing table rows with the title attributes of the latest row added. So if I had 2 "Chronic Pain Referral" rows then added a "Hospital Admission" row, it would convert the table into 3 "Hospital Admission" rows

Comment: No probl. `tr = xxx.append("...")` was incorrect, because append returns xxx, not the newly created element.